# How to learn Autofac fast for Windows development?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I'm about to start a project where the IoC being used is AutoFac - at a new company. I have no prior experience with DI/IoC and want to get up to speed on this so I don't look toooo unintelligent. This will be for a WPF application (which again I'm not too cluey about but that will be OK)

What are some good resources I could use to learn Autofac and IoC in general? I start in our initial phase on Monday next week :( I've held off everything this weekend to study!

I should mention that while the idea of IoC's are great, I don't see how we carry the "container" around with us when we use it in other areas. Do we create a singleton (that seam to say badness) or do we create a static class with an accessor to GetService?

EDIT: 
I am reading through the [codeproject article on Autofac](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/di-with-autofac.aspx) and sort of have an idea of what IoC is trying to solve via the NInject tutorial too, but nothing solid.

Comment: I found the wiki very helpful to get me up and running on AutoFac and IoC. http://code.google.com/p/autofac/w/list

Comment: You could read my book :) http://www.manning.com/seemann/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I put up a set of simple posts on Dependency Injection (and its benefits) [here](http://flexamusements.blogspot.com/2010/09/dependency-injection-part-0-tragedy.html). The whole thing should take perhaps 20 minutes to read.

Comment: Great read, thanks! I'm bookmarking that as my new go-to when someone asks me about Autofac again.

Comment: Excellnet Article you have posted, little bit indentation issue, specially about the coding, but its a great article.